# VueJS - counter doesn't increase when I click the button

Tags: vuejs2

I'm learning VueJS with *Maximilian Schwarzmüller* in his VueJS course on Udemy and whenever I run his example on my local machine, it doesn't increase my counter variable.

```
<div id="app">
  <button :click="increase">Click me</button>
  <p>{{ counter }}</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      counter: 0
    },
    methods: {
      increase() {
        return this.counter++
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Any idea what's wrong with the code?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `@` symbol for events, instead of `:` which is used for binding props.

```
<button @click="increase">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data` needs to be a function:

```
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        counter: 0
      }
    },
    ...
  })
</script>
```

Comment: `data(): {` isn't a valid syntax. There a unnecessary colon.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data: () => ({
   counter: 0,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script will execute before your document is ready therefore Vue will not find your element to mount to.

Also as others already mentioned - your `data` property should be a function to make each instance with unique data object.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', mountVue);

function mountVue() {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data() {
      return {
        counter: 0
      };
    },

    methods: {
      increase() {
        return this.counter++;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually this:

```
<button :click="increase">Click me</button>
```

I was using the wrong short-hand syntax. I had to use the `@` sign (for events) instead.

```
<button @click="increase">Click me</button>
```

I was looking at this example here on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Vpugh/pen/OmPrQE) and I noticed that their `data` object is not a *function*. Must the *data* object be a function? Are their benefits that I don't know about?

I'm very new to Vue right now and I'm learning from Max's course on Udemy. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You indeed found the main problem by yourself. The single colon `:` is shorthand for `v-bind`, whereas the `@` symbol is shorthand for `v-on`.
It's important to use a function that returns an object for your data when there might be more than one instance of a Vue component. If you were allowed to use a regular object here, the values in this object would be shared across all instances. For example: if you were to have multiple instances of a counter, using the same data, they would all increase if you increased one of them.

Comment: I took the same course quite a while ago, the topics you are wondering about are covered in the course. Lesson 26 is about vue directive shorthands. For now you don't really need to worry about using a function for your data, as the reasons for this will be extensively covered in section 7 of the course.